# Attempt to read property "id" on null in the HOSTING while in LOCAL work Just fine with Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

i have a search feature like this, when you click on the row, it will added to the list.

[image]

i've been trying to solve this about 3 days now. so i have the same version of the app in my local and my hosting. but i don't know why in the hosting will show error like this

[image]

while in my local works just fine

[image]

here is my code

on the `resources/views/livewire/kasir/query-barang.blade.php`

```
<div class="table-row cursor-pointer hover:bg-slate-700 hover:text-white"
                    wire:click="submit({{$br->barcode}})">
```

submit function on `app/Http/Livewire/Kasir/QueryBarang.php`

```
public function submit($barcode)
    {
        $this->emit('selectBarang', $barcode);
        $this->closeModal();
        $this->reset();
    }
```

and then the emit will listen by `app/Http/Livewire/Kasir/SearchBarang.php`

```
protected $listeners = [
        'selectBarang' => 'selectBarang'
    ];

public function selectBarang($barcode)
    {
        $this->barcode = $barcode;
        $this->submit();
    }

 public function submit()
    {
        /* Mengecek apakah barcode berbentuk numeric */
        if (is_numeric($this->barcode)) {
            /* jika true, maka akan menambahkan barang */
            $this->barang = Barang::where('barcode', $this->barcode)->first();
            $this->createOrUpdate();
        } else {
            /* Jika False maka akan mencari dan menampilkan Modal */
            $this->queryBarang($this->barcode);
            $this->reset('barcode');
        }
    }

public function createOrUpdate()
    {
        $checkBarangDalamList = TransaksiJualDetail::where('transaksi_jual_id', $this->transaksiJual)->where('barang_id', $this->barang->id)->first();
        if ($checkBarangDalamList == null) {
            $this->addNewStuff();
            $this->addTotal();
            $this->reset('barcode');
            $this->emit('storeNewList', $this->transaksiJual);
        } else {
            $this->addQuantity();
            $this->addTotal();
            $this->reset('barcode');
            $this->emit('storeNewList', $this->transaksiJual);
        }
    }
```

in the error as shown above, it clearly say that `$this->barang` is `null` . when i try to diedump `$this->barcode` on the submit function, it showing clearly what is the barcode
[image]

but, when i try to diedump `$this->barang` on the submit function it will showing me `null` value

[image]

What is wrong with my code ?
Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Hypothesis:** Two of your statements make me suspicious that ***it's a data issue***, not code.

1. In the submit function where `$this->barcode` has a value but `$this->barang` is null. The only operation is database query.

   $this->barang = Barang::where('barcode', $this->barcode)->first();
2. The issue happens in HOSTING while working on LOCAL. I assume your HOSTING environment and LOCAL environment use different databases.

**Propose Actions:** Please check whether the data is available in HOSTING as same as LOCAL.
You can use [firstOrFail()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-first-or-fail) collection instead of first() to detect and handle this error.

Comment: Hello, in this thread, i use my hosting database that i imported to my local database. after using firstOrFail() it showing 404 Not Found. what is the possibility cause the error ?

Comment: 404 is the itemNotFound Exception of firstOrFail.

however, glad that you finally solve it.

Answer (score 0):

after trying to fix this for 3 days, finally i got something that work. so i have to change the query from this

```
$this->barang = Barang::where('barcode', $this->barcode)->first();
```

to this

```
$this->barang = Barang::all()->where('barcode', $this->barcode)->first();
```

if you asking me what is the different, tbh i don't know. and i don't know either why it works.